# Move moderator comment banners?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

I'm seeing a few answers with what appears to be a special comment appended, like [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/17932/8207).

It strikes me that such a comment banner would be better placed between the answer and any following comments, and not at the bottom of the comments.

This is especially incongruous when the issue noted in the banner has been addressed by subsequent comments (which currently are visually above the banner).

Are there other issues or uses of those banners that give cause for the current positioning? If not, could they be shifted to be between answers and comments?

Comment: The current positioning also makes it unclear whether it's referring to the answer *above* or *below* the banner; it's actually most directly connected to the following answer if there is an answer after the one that has a mod post on it.

Comment: These banners are usually put on the question as a general warning, rather than on specific answers, to prevent the posting of inappropriate content. As such they appear between the question and answers and it's clearer what they refer to.

Comment: @Oddthinking - I realise that now :)

Comment: FYI Skeptics.SE are discussing a [similar issue](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1496/change-the-caveat-banner-on-posts), except proposing it should appear BEFORE the question.

Comment: This has [now been promoted to Meta.StackOverflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124891/move-position-of-post-notices-on-answers) as a feature-request. Please throw your weight behind it. (Unless you don't like it! Then go downvote it, so your opinion is heard!)